# How to encrypt my existing RDS Instance using Boto3?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, encryption, rds, boto3

I want to encrypt my existing rds instance.I am using the Boto Script to modify db instance.

```
modified_rds_attributes = rds_conn_boto3.modify_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier=id,
    StorageEncrypted=True
)
```

Is it possible to encrypt existing RDS DB Instance?
If Yes,then how can I acheive the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non encrypted instance cannot be converted to an encrypted one. You also cannot create an encrypted instance for a non encrypted snapshot or create an encrypted replica of a non encrypted instance.

The only way is to dump the old instance to a file and then load that into the new (encrypted) instance

Comment: The other answer to this question specifies an easier way to preserve data while enabling encryption on a copy of the original snapshot.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that "A non encrypted instance cannot be converted to an encrypted one." However , I disagree that there is one way to do the mission.

Another way is to :

1. take a snapshot from the unencrypted instance.
2. **copy** the snapshot by specifying a Key Management System (KMS) encryption key
3. then restore a new encrypted instance from snapshot

__

**Reference** https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-update-share-encrypted-snapshots-encrypt-existing-instances/

Comment: thanks for your answer , glad that i used this workaround. please upvote the Question if you find it useful :)

Comment: You can also re-encrypt an already encryted db by copying the snapshot and specifying the new key ID.